# Filter signal on oscilloscope using math functions

Tags: filter, oscilloscope, signal-processing, transfer-function, digital-filter

Is there a way to do a time domain low pass filter, in software, on a Siglent SDS2000X Plus series oscilloscope using these math functions?

[image]

The ones that stand out the most are `d/dt` and `∫dt`. However, there is no `sin(t)`, `cos(t)` :/

Comment: I like the way you're thinking! Can you Implement something like \$\int e^{\tau-t}C_1(t) \,\mathrm dt\$?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Nope, only \$e^{<contant>}\$. All operators can only be applied to some arbitrary constant or any of the 4 channels, \$C_{1-4}(t)\$.

Comment: hm, that's not to great. As the answer below points out, only if you have a way to access a delayed version of the signal, or weigh the history of the signal somehow, you get something like a filter (of course, the integral itself is an IIR filter, it's just not useful).

Answer (score 2):

I see `Avg`, so that's one lowpass, but it's not very malleable. Then you have integral and, if you can time-shift a signal, you get a moving average: `idt(x-delay(x,T))`. But perhaps a better option would be, if you can assign custom constants, you can write your own transfer function in time domain. For example, a generic 2nd order transfer function can be written like this, in both integral and derivative form:

$$\begin{align}
H(s)&=\dfrac{a_2s^2+a_1s+a_0}{b_2s^2+b_1s+b_0} \tag{1} \\
y(t)&=\dfrac{1}{b_2}\left\{a_2x(t)+\int{\left[a_1x(t)-b_1y(t)+\int{(a_0x(t)-b_0y(t))}\right]}\right\} \tag{2} \\
{}&=\dfrac{1}{b_0}\left\{a_0x(t)+a_1\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}x(t)+a_2\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}x(t)\right)-b_1\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}y(t)-b_2\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}y(t)\right)\right\} \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

Where I've written the derivatives as nested since it doesn't look like you have the option for second, or more, derivatives (but maybe I'm wrong). Pay attention to the indices(!). At any rate, I do not recommend using the derivative version due to possible noise (it's not mandatory, but it may be).

Just in case you have doubts, all three versions work (all three traces overlap completely):

[image: Laplace and time domain]

And a time-domain response for a sine with some 50 mVpk noise (the Laplace expression, `V(w)`, is known to not be very cooperative in `.TRAN`, in LTspice):

[image: time domain reponse]

Comment: Unfortunately, `Avg` is not a moving window average, it's an average between \$n\$ displayed/triggered waveforms.  
Delay option is possible, I could put the signal on a second channel and use the `deskew` channel setting, but unfortunately is limited to 100ns. I would have to use an external delay.
Time-domain transfer functions looks really promising, but I don't think they can be calculated in real-time in this form. I can't reference \$y(t)\$ in the formula, only \$x(t)\$ (the channel signal).

Comment: @Chris I never said `Avg` to be the moving average, I said it's a lowpass (fixed, since you get to see a constant over a fixed number of samples). Only then I mentioned the moving average: `idt(x-delay(x,T))`. If you can't reference the output then the denominator in (1) is not possible, which leaves your only other choice: a FIR, using the same time-shifted input, several times over (cumbersome). But the most efficient would be the moving average as described. `Intrp` (if it's iterpolation) is also a moving average. Last resort: zero out bins with `FFT`, but you'll get time domain artifacts.

Comment: I know, I know. What I was saying is that the way `Avg` is implemented on this oscilloscope cannot be used as an LPF. It's an average between waveforms, not subsequent samples. `Intrp` is also not usable as an LPF, because you can't subsample on oscilloscopes. Sample rate is automatic based on timebase and mem depth.

Comment: @Chris Looks like you're quite limited. What do those C, Z, and F buttons do? Alternatively, I see a "freq-analysis", maybe that ab has more options? Also, in the top menu, there's "analysis"?

Comment: Those are sources that can be used as arguments in functions: \$C_{1-4}\$ signal channels, \$Z_{1-4}\$ channel zooms, and \$F_{1-2}\$ functions to use the output of one function in another (only 2 math functions can be defined). "freq-analysis" has just `FFT`. "Formula Editor" has all the other tabs conglomerated into one (the other tabs have subsets of this). "analysis" has stuff like pulse search, counter, digital bus decoder, Bode plot and power analysis (input-output measurements)

Comment: @Chris Have you tried cheating? If `F1 = F1 - idt( a*C1 - b*F1 )` works, that would be a 1st order, `a/(s+b)`; 2nd order is next. Maybe it can be done by considering `F1[0]=0`. Worth trying. But if you need real-time filtering, you might be better off using a proper external filter.

Comment: Nah, it says sources incompatible.